# Member function of a C++ object as a CUDA __global__ function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, cuda

I have a base class:

```
  template <class T> 
  class A{
         public:
           // some data
           T data;
           //some functions like constructs etc.
            ...
           // one virtual function
           virtual void evaluate() = 0;

   }
```

and a derived class:

```
 template <class T> 
 class B:public A<T>{
          public:
          // some functions like constructors etc.
          virtual void evaluate();
          __global__ void function2();   // **** error message

 }
```

Also, I have

```
 template <class T> void
 B<T>::evaluate()
 { 
    dim3 grid(1);dim3 block(1);  
    void function2<<<grid,block>>>();
 }
```

and

```
template <class T>  __global__ void B<T>::function2() // **** error message 
{
   // computation here
}
```

so essentially I have a member function of a derived class which I would like to execute in a parallel fashion on the device.

Unfortunately, I get the error:

```
error : illegal combination of memory qualifiers on the lines :

1> __global__ void function2();   // **** error message

2> template <class T>  __global__ void B<T>::function2() // **** error message
```

I am new to CUDA. It would be very kind if someone points me to my error. I am developing on Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: `__global__` functions cannot be class static members in CUDA.

Comment: Here is the [documentation reference](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#classes) for @talonmies comment.

Comment: My comment will not add anything new to what talonmies and Robert Crovella have already pointed out to you. Do you really need to define `function2` as a static member function? I'm also using template classes with CUDA under Visual Studio 2010 and I'm defining all my `__global__` functions as non-member functions.

Comment: @talonmies I think this is sufficient as an answer.  If you would post it as an answer I would upvote it.

Comment: Last comment. I would say that your question is independent on whether the class is derived or not. Could this detail of your post have been skipped?

Comment: may i have a template then how to achieve what i am trying to do. for some "getting started" documentation i learnt that to implement a parallel function i need to put _global_ in front. and that is what i was trying. but i think my knowledge is not complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The template class definition in your first code snippet is illegal because it contains a __global__ function (CUDA kernel). As per the [language documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#classes), __global__ functions cannot be static class member functions. The second templated class member function is illegal for the same reason.