# CUDA: illegal combination of memory qualifiers

Tags: c++, cuda

I have the following code:

main.cu:

```
#include "class.h"
int main () {}
```

class.h:

```
class Class {
    __global__
    void Function() {};
};
```

When I compile this code using the command `nvcc -c main.cu -o main.o`, I get the following errors:

```
class.h(3): warning: inline qualifier ignored for "global" function
class.h(3): error: illegal combination of memory qualifiers
```

I have a question about each of these errors. Why does it "ignore" the `__global__` qualifier for the function, and why is the `__global__` memory qualifier illegal in this context? I have read in the [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#function-members) that

```
E.2.10.2. Function Members
Static member functions cannot be __global__ functions.
```

However, my function is not a static member, as far as I know. Removing the `__global__` line allows it to compile, and so does moving the `__global__` and `void Function();` lines into main.cu. If this actually ISN'T allowed, why does CUDA force this limitation, and what is a way to get around this while still maintaining structured code?

To clarify, I know no other way to make classes that have functions which can create GPU kernels. It seems to me like kernels can only be created from global functions in main.cu. I am fairly new to CUDA programming, so I may just be missing some CUDA conventions which may have been unclear to me. If this is the case, then please let me know so I can keep up with proper programming practice.

Comment: The short answer is no, you cannot do this.  If you google "cuda global class member" youll find a number of treatments of this, including SO questions like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17535959/member-function-of-a-c-object-as-a-cuda-global-function) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13748231/cuda-kernel-as-member-function-of-a-class), your question is arguably a duplicate of those.  As a simple suggestion, you could wrap your cuda kernels in host-callable class member functions, to " keep up with proper programming practice."

Comment: Hi @Robert, thank you for your comment. I just want to make sure I understand your suggestion. Are you recommending that I create a `__host__`function in my class, and the implementation of that function calls a `__global__` function? If so, what scope should the `__global__` function be in?

Comment: Yes, to the first question.  Not sure I understand the 2nd question.  Is there any lack of clarity around what scope the implementation of a class member function should be in?

Comment: Ok, I may understand now. The `__global__` qualifier is **not** independent from the idea of the global scope. That is, any `__global__` function **must** be a global function, in that it is defined in the global scope. I was under the understanding that `__global__` strictly meant that the function was defined on both the host and device, whereas a function in the global scope is accessible from any object on the host. If this explanation is correct, please post your answer as a formal answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My understanding is that you want to use CUDA kernels in an OOP fashion. If this was the case, the class structure below should work:

```
// myclass.h
class MyClass {
    public:
        void call_kernel( ... );
};

// myclass.cu
__global__
void my_kernel( ... ) {
    // do some work
}

void MyClass::call_kernel() {
    // prepare data for the kernel, e.g. allocating memory, copying from host to device, etc.

    // run kernel
    my_kernel <<< ... >>>( ... );

    // copy results from device to host, clean up, etc.
}
```

Please note that if you have multiple classes containing kernel code, their source code file should all use `.cu` extension, and you should enable [separate compilation](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/separate-compilation-linking-cuda-device-code/).